# Snort: Log request based on reply

Tags: ids, snort

I want to write a Snort rule that logs all HTTP requests where the reply contains a specific regex. Every rule I found only logs the packet it is currently evaluating (which would be the reply in my case), not a previous packet in the stream.

Is this possible with Snort?